# very versitile PHP dynamic queries

Tags: php, database, oop, abstraction

I am trying to abstract as much logic in my PHP classes right from the start. I have the names of all database tables as variables in my DBConnection class. Such as when a user calls `$db = new DBConnection();` it auto creates variables for all table names so that in all the queries i have so far I have things like `INSERT INTO $db->userTable (fields and constraints)` or `SELECT (fields) FROM $db->forumTable (constraints)`. However, how would be a good way to abstract column names where it is very versatile so that Im not hard coding column names into queries as well? so that if something like column names or something are changed, I dont have to go back and edit a ton of queries? Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1):

Write a database model in some language (possibly of your own choosing), a Domain Specific Language if you will. Use that model to *generate* your MySQL schema and whatever intermediate model or API you want to offer in PHP.

The model can include things like 'entity' names (not necessarily tables perse), properties and their type (number, text, enumeration, reference).

MySQL is already a very technical implementation and it's not very easy to manipulate. A Domain Specific Language will greatly aid data modeling and data consistency because you get so much for free. You are free of all the details MySQL offers, CHAR, VARCHAR, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, LONGTEXT, BLOB. For really generic applications you don't want to think about it.

**Update:** You want to 'abstract your logic'. You should start with abstracting your datamodel. Have a model that you can transform into MySQL queries that will build your database. You can use the same model to generate an API in PHP. Your model knows which entities there are (tables) and which properties and of which type so you can enforce them in PHP.

Comment: Im confused on what you mean. if you dont mind giving a small example. Im not following.

Comment: I've added an update. I don't know if I can explain it any differently, perhaps you've never heard about Domain Specific Langauges?

Comment: No I haven't heard of that. Although if you mean to create a class for each table I want to create and properties for each column etc, Ive done that a little bit with ASP.NET/NHibernate. But if thats what you mean, thats not a bad idea, but i still cant think of how to use this to create a dynamic column query so that if I add or subtract a column name, i dont want to hard code column names in queries. So i want to do something like SELECT $fields from $table WHERE $constraints. etc

Comment: Well Ill look up some info on that. Sounds enticing for sure. LOL So im guessing that what youre saying is that I define info in one place and it will be updated in both MySQL and PHP and a lot of the queries just by changing it one spot?

Answer (score 1):

Google Appengine has a query language and they have a nice `query class`implementation of the same. may be you can follow a similar structure...

Syntax looks something like this,

```
class Song(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    composer = db.StringProperty()
    date = db.DateTimeProperty()

query = Song.all()
query.filter('title =', 'Imagine')
```

Reference, [AppEngine Query Class](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html)